# Push not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a simple project where users can push or pop items onto the array. My problem is, when they push an item on and try to push another on, it doesn't add it onto the list, it simply replaces the last value that they added to the array.

```
window.onload = function menu(){
var array = ["cat", "dog"];
var selection = prompt("Please use this menu, and type 1 to push an item on the array, 2 to pop an item off the array, and 3 to exit the menu.");

if (selection == '1'){
  var push = prompt("What item would you like to push onto the array?");
    while (push != null) {  
      array.push(push);
      document.getElementById("pushed").innerHTML = array.toString();
      menu();
}}
```

Then down below I have an HTML page, but here is where it displays:

```
<div id = "pushed"></div>
```

Comment: Array is a local variable. You are recursively calling `menu` (which is a kind of bad design here anyway). Each time `menu` is called it is a new copy of `array`. Move the variable outside of the function and it will work. I'd still avoid a recursive function here though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `menu()` function redefines the array every time it is called, rather than modifying an array outside its scope.

Move the `var array = ['cat', 'dog'];` line to the top to solve this immediate problem.

```
var array = ["cat", "dog"];

function menu(){
    var selection = prompt("Please use this menu, and type 1 to push an item on the array, 2 to pop an item off the array, and 3 to exit the menu.");
    if (selection == '1'){
      var push = prompt("What item would you like to push onto the array?");
      while (push != null) {  
          array.push(push);
          document.getElementById("pushed").innerHTML = array.toString();
          menu();
        }
      }
}
window.onload = menu;
```

#### References

[JS Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

[onload usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: @GregL I think you need to add `()` like `window.onload=menu();` or revert back to my edit with the full function declaration.

Comment: @VinnyMannello I don't believe so. `window.onload` should be a function. Doing `window.onload = menu()` will assign the _return value_ of the `menu()` function (which is `undefined`) to the `window.onload` property, meaning it won't be run on load. The only reason you might not want to assign the function directly would be if the value of `this` was important in the `menu()` function. In this case, though, it is not.

Comment: @GregL, gotcha your explanation makes sense but if you toss it in a fiddle, `menu();` and `function () { menu(); }` work as expected, `menu;` does not. And ideas why?

Comment: @VinnyMannello Not at the moment. Can you post a fiddle to reproduce it? My suspicion is that it is due to the way jsFiddle runs stuff inside iframes or similar.